# DynamoDB music details storage and query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm actually building the backend of a music app using AWS (and DynamoDB).
I have to say I have limited knowledge on NoSQL and basic knowledge of SQL.

I'm actually building the storage of the music in DB.

The tables are:

**musicCatalog**

`musicId` -> index

`userId`  -> GSI

`album`

`nametrack`

`lenght`

`coverURL`

**musicCatalogExtended**

`musicId`

`genre : {
    "rock",
    "pop",
    "blues"
 }`

The user can select in app 1 -> 3 genres he wants to listen to.

The music can contain from 1 to 3 genres.

I've set up the  **musicCatalogExtended** table for genre as I've been reading it would be better this way.

**Problem:** I don't really know how to properly query in **musicCatalogExtended** to get items matching at least 1 genre from the user selection.

What should I put as index, since I can't set a list as it. 
How can I break down the problem to solve this?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Never mind, I found the solution after hours looking on stack : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557804/dynamodb-global-secondary-index-on-set-items

Comment: Feel free to delete this question if it is not going to benefit other readers.